# Clicking a checkbox on an ExpandableListView does not trigger the onChildClick event

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView which contains a list of rows with CheckBox and TextView.

I have managed get the row selectable by setting the checkbox focusable attribute to false.  I have also added a OnChildClickListener to my ExpandableListView.

When i click on the TextView or any other region, the onChildClick is executed fine.  But, the trouble is, when i click on the CheckBox, the onChildClick is not executed!!!

Any solutions or workaround???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do here is set the clickable attribute of the checkbox as false.  Then, you can programmatically check and uncheck the checkbox in your code with whatever else you need to do.

Comment: I have put a listener on the checkbox, but then there are two events that can be invoked.  One is the onChildClick event and the other one is the onCheckedChanged event.  I want to avoid this kind of scenario where i have two functions doing the same thing.